# Alarm/Cal Event repeating every alternate day and that which does not sync with google

Tags: calendar, clock

I need to create an alarm or calender event that repeats every alternate day at same time. I can not associate it with day of week, or date. I am using HTC Desire S.

I also need create entries in HTC Desire S calendar that which does not sync with Google calendars.

Comment: I am able to add such an event to Google Calendar and sync. But I don't want to have this on Google Calendar as it syncs with my Outlook.

Comment: Are you able to create a second calendar in your Google Calendar that doesn't sync to Outlook and adding it to that?

Comment: @GAThrawn, The Google Calendar Sync, syncs all the calendars to Outlook. I don't have an option to choose specific calendar.

Comment: When you say "alternate days of the week" is it always Monday, Wednesday, Friday, or is it literally alternate days and could be Mon, Weds, Fri, Sun one week, and then Tues, Thurs, Sat the next week?

Comment: @GAThrawn, I was saying literal alternate days (not alternate week days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application [Touch Calendar Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=uk.co.olilan.touchcalendar.trial)  create entries in phone-only calendar called 'PC Sync'. It also has repeat option as 'repeat every x day' where I have set as x=2. These entries are visible in HTC Calendar too.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event in Google Calendar with the repeat/reminder frequency that you want.

To avoid synchronizing the event with external calendars, put the event on a phone-private calendar: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168512&topic=21414#1077952

Comment: Somehow I don't have 'eye' icon on my mobile.

Comment: Can you create a separate calendar and just not sync that to Outlook?  See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=7c043560b80212cc&hl=en.  Can you edit your question to include the not-sync'ing in the title and body, too?

Comment: I created an entry in HTC Calendar app with PC Sync as the selected Calendar. It doesn't sync with Google, which solves one of my need. But, as already said, HTC Calendar can not create entries repeating alternate days. Here is where I miss Nokia Symbian. Any idea if new versions of Android (2.3.5) or HTC Sense 3.0 have it?

Comment: @TheMaskOfZero I don't know if new versions are better.  You might look at alternative Calendar apps in the market?  I believe the limitations you're hitting are in the app, and not platform limitations.

Comment: Finally I got the solution. The app in the market called 'Touch Calendar Free' was able to create entries in phone-only calendar called 'PC Sync'. It also has repeat option as 'repeat every x day' where I have set as x=2. These entries are visible in HTC Calendar too.

Answer (score 0):

In the Clock app, you could create two alarms. One that's set to go off on Monday, Wednesday, Friday, and Sunday; and the other to Tuesday, Thursday, and Saturday. Then you just need to alternate which one is off and which is on each week.

Not a perfect solution, but it will work with the built-in tools. (Otherwise you're going to need to get someone to write you a custom solution.)